# Add upload picture functionality for registration page in wordpress theme

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

In my theme, there's a registration page where user can register by submitting some details. But there's a new requirement now where I have to add upload photo feature where user have to upload a photo of them and it will be their profile photo. After inspecting the theme I found out that there are 3 files which are responsible for a successful page registration.

**Page registration HTML**

```
...
<div class="fr-sign-form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="emp_profile_pic"><?php echo esc_html__('Upload your live Picture', 'exertio_theme'); ?></label>
            <div class="upload-btn-wrapper">
                <label for="emp_profile_pic">Profile Picture:</label>
                <input type="file" id="emp_profile_pic" name="emp_profile_pic" accept="image/*" data-post-meta="_profile_pic_freelancer_id">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
...
```

**Custom.js** 
This is where ajax request is initiated...I had changed some lines to get the serialized data of the form, including the image. but here I'm getting the image name only as parameter.

```
$("#signup-btn").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if ($("form#signup-form").smkValidate()) {
        var this_value = $(this);
        this_value.find("span.bubbles").addClass("view");
        $("#signup-btn").attr("disabled", true);
        var redirect_id = $(this).attr("data-redirect-id");

        var serializedData = $("form#signup-form").serialize();

        // Get the selected profile pic
        var empProfilePicInput = $("#emp_profile_pic")[0];
        if (empProfilePicInput.files.length > 0) {
            var empProfilePic = empProfilePicInput.files[0];
            serializedData += "&emp_profile_pic_name=" + empProfilePic.name;
        }

        console.log("Serialized Form Data:", serializedData);

      $.post(localize_vars.freelanceAjaxurl, {
        action: "sign_up",
        signup_data: serializedData,
        // signup_data: formData,
        security: $("#register_nonce").val(),
        redirect_id: redirect_id,
      })
        .done(function (response) {
          var get_notification = response.split("|");
          console.log(get_notification);
          
          if ($.trim(get_notification[0]) == "1") {
            $("#signup-btn").attr("disabled", false);
            toastr.success(get_notification[1], "", {
              timeOut: 8000,
              closeButton: true,
              positionClass: "toast-top-right",
              showMethod: "slideDown",
              hideMethod: "slideUp",
            });
            if (get_notification[3] != "") {
              this_value.find("span.bubbles").removeClass("view");
              $("#fl_user_id").val(get_notification[3]);
              $(".fr_resend_email").css("display", "block");

              // window.location = get_notification[2];
              if (
                get_notification[3] == "https://labour.dev40.xyz/upload-resume"
              ) {
                window.location = get_notification[3];
              }
            } else if (get_notification[2] != "") {
              window.location = get_notification[2];
            }
          } else {
            this_value.find("div.bubbles").removeClass("view");
            $("#signup-btn").attr("disabled", false);
            toastr.error(get_notification[1], "", {
              timeOut: 8000,
              closeButton: true,
              positionClass: "toast-top-right",
              showMethod: "slideDown",
              hideMethod: "slideUp",
            });
          }
        })
        .fail(function () {
          this_value.find("div.bubbles").removeClass("view");
          $("#signup-btn").attr("disabled", false);
          toastr.error($("#nonce_error").val(), "", {
            timeOut: 8000,
            closeButton: true,
            positionClass: "toast-top-right",
          });
        });
    
     }
  });
```

**Registration.php** 
this file is responsible for saving user data in DB.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_sign_up', 'sign_up');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_sign_up', 'sign_up');
if (!function_exists('sign_up')) {
    function sign_up()
    {
        /*DEMO DISABLED*/
        exertio_demo_disable('echo');
        check_ajax_referer('fl_register_secure', 'security');
        $params = array();
        parse_str($_POST['signup_data'], $params);



        global $exertio_theme_options;
        global $wpdb;
        $base_prefix = $wpdb->base_prefix;
        if (isset($params['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
            if (!exertio_recaptcha_verify($exertio_theme_options['google_recaptcha_secret_key'], $params['g-recaptcha-response'], $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], '')) {
                echo "0|" . esc_html__("Please verify captcha.", 'exertio_framework');
                die();
            }
        }
        if (email_exists($params['fl_email']) == false) {
            if ($wpdb->get_row("SELECT post_name FROM " . $base_prefix . "posts WHERE post_name = '" . $params['fl_username'] . "'", 'ARRAY_A')) {
                echo '0|' . __('Username already exist', 'exertio_framework');
                die;
            } else {
                /*its only for registration type*/
                global $wp_session;
                if (isset($params['exertio_user_type']) && $params['exertio_user_type'] == 'employer') {
                    $wp_session['loggedInAs'] = 'employer';
                } else if (isset($params['exertio_user_type']) && $params['exertio_user_type'] == 'freelancer') {
                    $wp_session['loggedInAs'] = 'freelancer';
                }

                $user_args = array(
                    'user_pass'             => $params['fl_password'],
                    'user_nicename'            => sanitize_text_field($params['fl_username']),
                    'user_login'            => sanitize_text_field($params['fl_username']),
                    'display_name'             => sanitize_text_field($params['fl_full_name']),
                    'user_email'            => sanitize_text_field($params['fl_email']),
                );
                $uid =    wp_insert_user($user_args);
                add_user_meta($uid, 'fl_user_type', sanitize_text_field($params['fl_user_type']), false);
                add_user_meta($uid, 'fl_full_name', sanitize_text_field($params['fl_full_name']), false);
                add_user_meta($uid, 'fl_contact_number', sanitize_text_field($params['fl_contact_number']), false);
                add_user_meta($uid, 'fl_country', sanitize_text_field($params['fl_country']), false);

                if (isset($params['emp_profile_pic_name'])) {
                    $emp_profile_pic_name = sanitize_text_field($params['emp_profile_pic_name']);
                 
                    update_user_meta($uid, '_profile_pic_freelancer_id', $emp_profile_pic_name);
                }

                $redirect = $_POST['redirect_id'];
                if (isset($redirect) && $redirect != '') {
                    $page = get_the_permalink($redirect);
                } else {
                    $page = get_the_permalink($exertio_theme_options['user_dashboard_page']);
                }
                if (fl_framework_get_options('fl_allow_user_email_verification') == false) {
                    $user = array();
                    $user = new WP_User($uid);
                    foreach ($user->roles as $role) {
                        $user->remove_role($role);
                    }
                    //
                    exertio_account_activation_email($uid);
                    $page = get_the_permalink($exertio_theme_options['registration_page']);
                    echo '1|' . __("A verification link has been sent to your email account.", 'exertio_framework') . '|' . $page . '|' . $uid;
                    die;
                } else {
                    fl_auto_login($params['fl_email'], $params['fl_password'], false);
                }

                $str = '1|' . __("Registration successfull. Redirecting....", 'exertio_framework') . "|" . $page . "|" . "";
                if ($params['fl_user_type'] == 'Job Seekers') {
                    $str .= "https://labour.dev40.xyz/upload-resume";
                }

                echo $str;
                die;
            }
        } else {
            echo '0|' . __('Email already exist, please try other one.', 'exertio_framework');
            die;
        }
    }
}
```

As I had added some custom checks for `$params['emp_profile_pic_name']` i'm getting the image name only. which is of no use I need to be able to get the data from DB. 
I had also inspected the code for updating profile which was already there. There I can see they were retrieving the image with the help of `$pid`

```
$pid = get_user_meta($current_user_id, 'freelancer_id', true);
$pro_img_id = get_post_meta($pid, '_profile_pic_freelancer_id', true);
$pro_img = wp_get_attachment_image_src($pro_img_id, 'thumbnail');
```

so If I log that, I got an id...so the id is pointing to the uploaded image. So how do i achieve the same in the registration page? I've been trying this for the whole day and I couldn't solve this. So any suggestions will be much appreciated.